# Path bar missing in file dialog after running software updater for Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: unity, 17.04, dialog

After running software updater, the path bar in the file dialog (for example the one you get when choosing *Open File* in in Google Chrome or Firefox) is missing. This is frustrating since it's no longer possible to copy a path from the terminal (for example) and paste it into the file dialog. Here is a screenshot of the dialog:

[image]

How can I get back the path bar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's something called the [breadcrumb bar/view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation)), you can switch to the classic view by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.